# Submitting Forms generated in a for loop

Tags: forms, angular

I'm generating forms from an array of JSON objects. My HTML template looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let module of inputModules">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(module)">
            {{module.name}}
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let arg of module.args">
                    <input type="file" id="{{ arg.name }}">
                    <p>{{ arg.description }}<p>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button type="submit">Run</button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I've got a list of modules that each have a list of files they need. I'm using this to quickly display lots of forms on the same page.

I would like to POST these forms "on submit", along with their inputs, in the most direct way possible. I'm not sure how I can use the "two-way" `[(ngModel)]` when my forms are procedurally generated like this.

Ideally what I would like is a way to just say "POST this form", without having to use the two-way data bindings which doesn't seem possible given how my forms are created.

My service `InputService` looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class InputService {
    ...

    runModule(name): Promise<string> {
        var url = this.runModuleURL + name;
        var params = ???

        return this.http
            .post(url, params, {headers: this.headers})
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    handleError(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

And my component looks like this:

```
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {    
    onSubmit(module): void {
        // console.log(this.formData);
        this.inputService.runModule(module.name).then(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: @RyanVincent I'm not sure I understand your question? There's a button for each form, clicking on the button should submit _that_ form only. I would just like a way to tell my component to get the form parameters without bindings.

Comment: my bad. I misunderstood your explanation. - sorry